# Issue in querying graphQL relay calls (.then is not a function)

Tags: graphql, relay, graphql-js

I have a graphql server running which I am using for query one of the object that gets instantiated when server starts (kind of in-memory db). Here company object is created every time schema is loaded or say server is started which I am using in QueryType object to resolve.

Here is the graphQL Schema

```
const {
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLList
    } = require('graphql');
const {
    connectionDefinitions,
    connectionArgs,
    connectionFromArray,
    connectionFromPromisedArray
    } = require('graphql-relay');




//**************************** In-Memory Data ********************************//
var company = {
    id:'123456',
    customFieldDefinitions:[
        {
            name: 'cfm1',
            id: '123'
        },
        {
            name: 'cfm2',
            id: '1234'
        }
    ]
};
//**************************** In-Memory Code Ends *********************************//


const CustomFieldDefinitionType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Common_CustomFieldDefinitionsConnection',
    fields: {
        id: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resolve: (cfd) => cfd.id
        },
        name: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resolve: (cfd) => cfd.name
        }
    }
});

const { connectionType: CustomFieldDefinitionConnection } =
    connectionDefinitions({
        name: 'Common_CustomFieldDefinition',
        nodeType: CustomFieldDefinitionType
    });


const CompanyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Company',
    fields: {
        id: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resolve: (obj) => obj.id
        },
        customFieldDefinitions: {
            type: CustomFieldDefinitionConnection,
            description: 'A list of Custom Fields',
            args: connectionArgs,
            resolve: (obj, args) => connectionFromPromisedArray(obj.customFieldDefinitions, args)
        }
    }
});

const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
        company: {
            args: {
                id: { type: GraphQLString },
            },
            type: CompanyType,
            resolve: (_, args) => company
        }
    }
});

const mySchema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: QueryType
});

module.exports = mySchema;
```

Now when I try to query as below on graphiQL editor

```
query{
  company{
    customFieldDefinitions {
      edges {
        node {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get error as below.

```
{
  "data": {
    "company": {
      "customFieldDefinitions": null
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "dataPromise.then is not a function",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "company",
        "customFieldDefinitions"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I identify the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the error is with this line:

`resolve: (obj, args) => connectionFromPromisedArray(obj.customFieldDefinitions, args)`

The problem is that the `connectionFromPromisedArray` function imported from `graphql-relay` expects a promise that returns an array and `obj.customFieldDefinitions` is a normal array. Just to trace it back, `obj` is the parent element of that resolver which in this case is what you return from the `company` resolver on the `Query` type.

To fix it, either change `connectionFromPromisedArray` to `connectionFromArray` or change your company object to this:

```
var company = {
  id:'123456',
  customFieldDefinitions: Promise.resolve([
    {
      name: 'cfm1',
      id: '123'
    },
    {
      name: 'cfm2',
      id: '1234'
    }
  ])
};
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. That was the issue

Comment: Happy to help! Best of luck.